# how to use one of mysql database column as variable with VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this table in my mySQl database:

```
ID   First_Name  Second_Name   Age   RFID_Tag    Amount_Serve
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1     John         Smith      28     hdgdYun8JH   Small
 2     George        Mark      35     kdjfHluhHB    Big
```

and have this code for mysql query

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim str As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=namesdb;Uid=root;Pwd=1234"

    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)
        Dim query As String = "select * from namedata where rfid_tag=@rfid"
        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(query, con)

        con.Open()
        cm.Parameters.Add("@rfid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text

        Dim rd As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()

        ' Check if any rows exist
        If rd.HasRows = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("trun on sm")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not your time")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

what I want is when the rfid tag in textbox3.text equal the rfid tag in table I want to use IF function form if that rfid amount serve Small run python script for small and if big run script for Big
What I think is to replayce:

```
If rd.HasRows = True Then
```

to be something like this if Amount_server = Small then

I hope I made it clear any help for this case please.

Comment: Something like `rd.GetString(5)` or `rd["Amount_Serve"].ToString()` should be enough to retrieve the data and store it inside a string variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply to help but I want to be clear please..for this rd.GetString(5) I have to replace 5 with  Amount_serve column name?

Comment: @Tetsuya I tried this: If [rd.GetString("Amount_Serve") = "small"] Then . I got this error [Additional information: Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()]

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I want it something like this which can take decision upon mount_serve column with compare rfid column
          (`If (rd.Read()) Then

                rd.GetString("Amount_Serve") = small 

                MessageBox.Show("OK")


            Else

                MessageBox.Show("Not your time")
                End If`)

Comment: Note that what you are after is not a column at all, just a value in a database.  Clear questions get more and better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks for @TetsuyaYamamoto to give me the hint!

The solution was like this:

```
If rd.Read() Then
            If rd.GetString(4) = "small" Then


                MessageBox.Show("small")


            ElseIf rd.GetString(3) = "Big" Then

                MessageBox.Show("big")
            End If
        End If
```

Thanks for all